# ServletRequestParameter exception, parameter is not present

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, postman

I am creating an API, using Spring Boot and using PostMan to debug and test the system. Now I am having a difficulty in sending a class object as a parameter.

I wish to send an Entity passed as a parameter and display whether the entity has a specified certification or not.

Currently I am using Postman and using the raw "JSON" format to display my Entity Object, however I am getting an error

```
"resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Entity parameter 'store' is not present]"
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what the problem could be

My JSON  (this is the Entity CLass Object that I created, I am not able to recieve a response from the API, the API should send the string "Passed Check"

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "asdasd",
    "phoneNumber": "000",
    "address": "asdasdasdasdasd",
    "latitude": 0.0,
    "longitude": 0.0,
    "dateAdded": "06/08/2020"
}
```

**Certification Controller**

```
@Controller
public class CertController {

@Autowired
private CertificationRepository certRepo;
@Autowired
private StoreRepository StoreRepository;

@GetMapping(value = "/getCertification")

@GetMapping(value = "/getCertObject")
public @ResponseBody
String getCertificationPOJO(@RequestParam Entity store)
{
    return "Passed check";

}

}
```

**Postman Error**

[image: POSTMAN Error]

Comment: Use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam` you want the body of the request to be deserialized you don't want to bind a request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you shared, I see a few issues.

1. Missing Path to Controller

Add @RequestMapping("/cert") on CertController.

```
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/cert")
public class CertController {
}
```

2. Wrong Parameter Type

`getCertificationPOJO` method should have `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam` annotation

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getCertObject")  
public @ResponseBody String getCertificationPOJO(@RequestBody Entity store) {
    return "Passed check";
}
```

You can easily follow this guide: [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)